# Add uuid field in django Existing User model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-users

I am using Django Rest framework for my application. I almost implemented registration and login process using django User Model without customizing it now i want to add a uuid field in it. Is there any way we can just add uuid field and other process remains same?

Comment: Take a look here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractuser

Answer (score 6):

Adding [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField) to existing models is not so easy but you can read an How-To in the official Django documentation in the specific section (*I updated it few months ago*) :

[Migrations that add unique fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields).

Comment: I went through the steps and it all worked ok except whenever I run makemigrations I get `Alter field uuid on mymodel` ?

Comment: What's your question ? Can you write clearly your question or better can you open a new question because is not related to this original question.

Comment: Every time I run migrations it thinks I have altered the field. This is the migrations statement "- Alter field qrcode on profile" where qrcode is my uuid object and profile is the model

Comment: Sorry figured it out. My django model was `default=uuid.uuid4()` instead of `default=uuid.uuid4`

Comment: Ok. If you found useful this answer maybe you can vote for it thanks.